# String replacement inside powershell. is this possible

Tags: powershell

I have the following Sharepoint PowerShell script where I am creating a new page. Now I want to replace all the images src. Currently the images source will be as follows:

```
src="/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/test2/1153210.png"
src="/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/test3/11536.png"
src="/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/main/3d.png"
src="/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/detailed/list.png"
```

but I want to remove the folder name after `Pages` - so the above will look like this:

```
src="/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/1153210.png"
src="/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/11536.png"
src="/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/ed.png"
src="/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/list.png"
```

This markup will be part of the whole page source code. I am not sure if PowerShell will allow me to do this kind of string replacement?

Answer (score 2):

use something like this:

```
$Strings = @("src=""/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/test2/1153210.png""",
"src=""/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/test3/11536.png""",
"src=""/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/main/3d.png""",
"src=""/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/detailed/list.png""",
"src=""/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/already_in_root.png""")

foreach ($String in $Strings){
    $String -replace '(.+Images/Pages).*?(/.*)','$1$2'
}
```

which will output

```
src="/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/1153210.png"
src="/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/11536.png"
src="/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/3d.png"
src="/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/list.png"
src="/kb/Group/PublishingImages/Pages/already_in_root.png"
```

you can easily adjust the regex to match any folder structure, or read `$Strings` from a file instead.